# how to send utf-8 encoded strings with volley post request android

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8

I am using volley library for sending network requests in my android app. 
I am sending StringRequest using POST method and sending post parameters using

> getParams() method.

Now I want to send some of the strings in these post parameters with UTF-8 encoding. I have tried adding the below for this.

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
   return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
}
```

But it is not working fine. 
I have tried adding headers using getHeaders function also but it is also not working.

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
    header.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    return header;
}
```

How can I do this, please help me if anyone have any idea about it.

Comment: `But it is not working fine`. What do you mean ? Please be exact. `but it is also not working.` What is "not working"?. I wonder why you want to do anyting concerning utf-8. Isn't that default behaviour? Which problems did you encounter? Tell all in your post. Not in comments.

Comment: Show us your `getParams()` method

Comment: I have managed it by adding the below to the string.

`byte[] bytes = "hello".getBytes("UTF-8");
 String body = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));` and now I am able to send UTF-8 encoding with this string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your text to `UTF-8` and post

```
byte[] bytes = "text".getBytes("UTF-8"); 
String sendBody = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```